# Do I (and how do I) need to write my own ACOSJ Javacard garbage collection, or is it automatic?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, smartcard, javacard

Do I need to write my own garbage collection when using an ACOSJ javacard? Or is it done automatically?

If I do need to write my own - are there any useful guides online that show me how I can do this? Or any specific ways of doing this that I should do/avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Garbage collection is supported from Javacard 3.0.2. You don't need to do implementation just transient variables are collected when calling `JCSystem.requestObjectDeletion` method in your applet.

for more information check [this](https://askra.de/software/jcdocs/app-notes-2.2.1/garbagecoll.html) link.

Comment: Thank you - so do I need to call `JCSystem.requestObjectDeletion` at some point in my applet or else have a memory leak?

Comment: If you don't do garbage collection, it doesn't mean your memory leaks. Garbage collection only helps saving your memory for future use.

Comment: Ah I see - the problem I'm having is that I seem to be bricking cards after using my app on them for a while. I assumed it was a memory issue from the research I'd done online, as I wasn't going garbage collection

Comment: @LozCodes always define you variables outside of methods inside the applet class and initialize them in class constructor. In addition, transient objects are collected when calling requestObjectDeletion. Try to use my first tip to prevent breaking your card due to memory problems.

Comment: Thank you - I think that might be what the problem is

Comment: @LozCodes This is a very good example for garbage collection in java card: https://javacardos.com/wiki/javacard-api-samples/storage